# CORDIC for square roots

Tags: c++, cordic

I have been looking at the CORDIC algorithm in hyperbolic rotation mode to find the square root of a variable.  I am unsure what my initial variables should be (x0, y0, z0) to find the 
square root. I have read some papers, citing that to find the sqrt(a), initial values should be set to a+1,a-1,0 for x0,y0,and z0 respectively.  Others says it should be a+0.25,a-0.25,0.  I am very confused by this

Can anyone help?

```
double x = (64.0+1);
double y = (64.0-1);
double z = 0; 


double k = 3;
double n = 1;
while(n <= 20 ){

    double xn = pow(2.0,-1.0*n) * x;
    double yn = pow(2.0,-1.0*n) * y;

    if(y < 0){ 
        x = x + xn;
        y = y + yn;
        z = z - atanh(pow(2.0,-1.0*n));
    }
    else
    {
        x = x - xn;
        y = y - yn;
        z = z + atanh(pow(2.0,-1*n));

    }

    if(k > 0){
        k = k-1;
    }
    else{
        k = 3;
        if(y < 0){ 
            x = x + xn;
            y = y + yn;
            z = z - atanh(pow(2.0,-1.0*n));
        }
        else
        {
            x = x - xn;
            y = y - yn;
            z = z + atanh(pow(2.0,-1.0*n));

        }
    }
    n++;
    cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << endl;
}
```

EDIT* 
Along with compensating for 3j+1 repeats, CORDIC requires to execute the loop twice in instances such as n = 4,13,40, ...  I have updated my code to compensate for that, but it still does not work. 
I am using hyperbolic rotation in vectoring mode, which the variable `d` should be based on sign of y

EDIT*
Turns out that CORDIC can fail when computing larger square root values, so you have to normalize the number you are trying to find the square root of to 0.5 to 2 range, then scale back answer back up.

Comment: Unrelated comment:  I hadn't heard CORDIC mentioned in 30-odd years.  It was the basis of the old HP 9100 desktop calculator, ca 1968, which, after being integrated circuitedized, became the original HP pocket calculator line.  (Know very little about the algorithm, though, other than that it was defined by a diode array ROM occupying most of the roughly 18-inch-square circuit board that filled the bottom of the calculator.)

Comment: todays FPGAs still use it

Comment: I'm a little surprised.  IIRC, it was not particularly fast, but had the advantage that virtually all transcendental functions could be implemented with the same basic, very simple framework, just different parameters.

Comment: You're correct.  It is not particularly fast but it maximizes throughput with its simple scheme.  Well, I say simple, yet I am having issues..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normalize the number you are performing the square root on to [0.5,2) range, then scale back up accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like you finally got it working!  And normalizing does have a vaguely familiar ring to it -- IIRC, the arguments for most of the functions had to be pre-normalized to stay in the range where the algorithm converged.

Comment: Exactly.  It made sense to normalize when I noticed my algorithm was converging less and less for larger inputs.

Answer (score 3):

> initial values should be set to a+1,a-1,0 for x0,y0,and z0 respectively. Others says it should be a+0.25,a-0.25,0. I am very confused by this

The final result is `sqrt((a+1)^2 - (a-1)^2)` or `sqrt((a+0.25)^2 - (a-0.25)^2)`.  Either way the `a^2` terms cancel and the constant terms cancel.   The only difference is the first version returns `sqrt(4a)` or `2sqrt(a)` and the second one returns `sqrt(a)` directly.  I don't know the numerical reasons why one case or the other might be preferred.

Edit:  Your bug is setting `d` based on `y`, it should be based on `z`.

Comment: I thought using vectoring mode, would depend on changes in y?

Comment: Hm, my memory must be slightly off:  The difference between `0.25` and `1` as the offset values is definitely a change in the result by a factor of 4, but it seems to go the other way (testing with a fixed version of your code).

Comment: is all that you changed the if/else loop setting the values of d?  Doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer: I had to change it in a few places due to the cut/paste used to replicate the n=4,13 cases, but yes, that's all I changed besides wrapping it in `main()` and adding the includes.

Comment: You know, this program was converging to 5 for your original example so I didn't look too closely at the rest, but lo and behold it converges to 5 for 64, too!  One more thing I just noticed is that you start with `n=0`, but that's your base case, your first iteration should be `n=1`.  There must be more as well, but that's why `z=inf` (due to `atanh(2^0)=atanh(1)=inf`)

Comment: Ah, yes, I have fixed that issue.  Even updated my code(see above edits) so that the 3j-1 repeats are handled in one if/else statement.  However, sqrt(25) converges at 6.77 and sqrt(64) around 17.24.  I still think basing d on y is the right way to go, since I am in vectoring mode

Comment: There _is_ a reason why I prefer initializing with `X=z+1, Y=z-1, T=0`, with `z` in the range [0.5, 2]. Namely, when this is done, not only does `X` become `2 sqrt(z)`, but _also_ `T` becomes `0.5 ln(z)`, since `ln z = 2atanh((z-1)/(z+1))`. I've got no idea what initialization with 0.25 would have evaluated instead for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs in the code!

1. The variables are not exchanged.

```
     x = x + xn;
     y = y + yn;
```

should be:

```
     x = x + yn;
     y = y + xn;
```

2. The iteration 4 and 13 are not properly repeated.
   The following needs to be recomputed in those branches:

```
     xn = pow(2.0,-1.0*n) * y;
     yn = pow(2.0,-1.0*n) * x;
```

3. Scale correction should be done on the output (`x/2*1.207497`).

See here for ugly debugged, but working code:
https://godbolt.org/z/ma4dCV

Note also, there is no need for the whole `z` channel (https://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/examples/compute-square-root-using-cordic.html).